# Mschart Add custom Textbox

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, mschart

Is it possible to add a custom textbox to a mschart?
Example I have a graph, the axislabels, the legend to the right.
I want to add a custom text(box) to the chartarea with a textbox with an explaning text about the graph. The reason is because its so easy to save an image of the chart so I want the explanation to be integrated in the picture.

Regards
//JH

Comment: you can just use chart title to give description about chart...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @rockyashkumar, you could use chart title to explain the figure.

You can do that using `chart.Titles` property, either through visual studio designer or programmatically e.g.:

```
var title = this.chart1.Titles.Add("The title text");
// set other properties of the title (if necessary)
title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Chart = CreateChartTemplate();
    Title area1Title = new Title(chartTitle, Docking.Top, new Font("Verdana", 12), Color.Black);
    area1Title.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
    area1Title.Docking = Docking.Top;
    Chart.Titles.Add(area1Title);
```

You can use this to set a title on top of the graph outside of the plotted area, you can also change options if you would like it inside chart area.

```
area1Title.DockedToChartArea
```

this will allow you to specify an area of the chart to fix it to. i.e top left right etc.